# C - properly importing stdcall functions from unmanaged DLL

Tags: c, winapi, dll, dllexport, stdcall

I am trying to import a function from an unmanaged DLL into a C project by creating a .def file specifying the function I need to use. I am practicing on the WinAPI function `MessageBoxA` from `user32.dll`. It is an stdcall function, like the other WinAPI functions.
Here's how I create my .def file:

```
LIBRARY user32.dll
EXPORTS
_MessageBoxA@16
```

Then I create a .lib from it like this: `lib /def:"C:\Path\to\def\user32.def" /
out:"C:\path\to\project\user32-mb.lib"` which successfully creates `user32-mb.lib` and `user32-mb.exp`. Then, in my C project, I do the following:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32-mb.lib")

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

EXTERNC __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall MessageBoxA(void *hWnd, char *lpText, char *lpCaption, int uType);

void main(){
    MessageBoxA(0, "MessageBox test", "MessageBox test", 0x00000030L);
}
```

However, upon linking, it gives the following error:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MessageBoxA@16 referenced in function _main`

However, when I change the declaration in the .def to this:

```
LIBRARY user32.dll
EXPORTS
MessageBoxA
```

And change the function prototype in my C code to `cdecl` instead of `stdcall`:

`EXTERNC __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl MessageBoxA(void *hWnd, char *lpText, char *lpCaption, int uType);`
The message box actually appears, but right on closing, it throws an error:

`Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.`
Which indicates that calling it with `cdecl` is also a bad idea since it requires `stdcall` after all.

The question is, what should I change in the .def file or in my project to avoid both errors and to import and call an `stdcall` function properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not entirely sure why, but removing the `_` adding the ordinal to the function name my `.def` file fixed everything. My solution is:

```
LIBRARY USER32.dll
EXPORTS
MessageBoxA@16 @2093
```

Function definition:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

typedef void *PVOID;
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
typedef HANDLE HWND;
typedef const char *LPCSTR;
typedef unsigned int UINT;

EXTERNC __declspec(dllimport)
int
__stdcall
MessageBoxA(
    HWND hWnd,
    LPCSTR lpText,
    LPCSTR lpCaption,
    UINT uType);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I'll be able to accept it only in 2 days. In the meantime, does anybody know why declaring the ordinal was so important?

Comment: Is it really the correct answer? If you don't understand, perhaps it isn't.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it is the correct answer because it works. Why it works is a completely different question ;)

Comment: @Mints97 it works because [using DEF changes the mangling scheme](http://www.willus.com/mingw/yongweiwu_stdcall.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `__declspec(dllexport)` to `__declspec(dllimport)`, as you are *importing* functions from a DLL, not *exporting* them:

```
EXTERNC __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall MessageBoxA(void *hWnd, char *lpText, char *lpCaption, int uType);
                      ^^
```

Comment: DEF file: `LIBRARY user32.dll
EXPORTS
_MessageBoxA@16` and changed the line in the project as you said. Now it says it can't find `__imp__MessageBoxA@16`

Comment: You might try adding that symbol to the `EXPORTS` part of the DEF file as well

Comment: def file: `LIBRARY user32.dll
EXPORTS
_MessageBoxA@16
__imp__MessageBoxA@16` exactly the same error

Comment: Hmm. I've seen some assembly programs that use `MessageBoxA@16`, i.e. no leading underscore. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Windows machine ATM, so I can't test anything.

Comment: Don't use dllimport either, he didn't declare the function pointer.  Just remove it completely.

Comment: @HansPassant: DEF file: `LIBRARY user32.dll
EXPORTS
_MessageBoxA@16` declaration in C: `EXTERNC int __stdcall MessageBoxA(void *hWnd, char *lpText, char *lpCaption, int uType);` It can't find _MessageBoxA@16.

Comment: @HansPassant are you sure? Because `winuser.h` uses `dllimport`, so why shouldn't OP use it as well? (yes, it's linking to a different lib, but that seems irrelevant)

Comment: I'm sure.  His .lib is incomplete, it doesn't also declare the __imp__MessageBoxA@16 function pointer.  The one that's used when you use dllimport.

Comment: @HansPassant: but I've tried declaring __imp__MessageBoxA@16 too in the def file, see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `dllimport` rather than `dllexport`, but in this case you should remove the `__declspec(...)` altogether.

And you need to specify the correct name for the function which is `MessageBoxA`.

```
LIBRARY USER32.dll
EXPORTS
  MessageBoxA
```

Also it would be remiss of me not to point out that the correct main declaration is

```
int main(void)
```

Comment: @vaxquis it's needed to avoid unwanted name decoration

Comment: I've re-read the OPs question a couple of times... and I still think the question is lousy and I still don't see any need for DEFs here - OP could either just use MinGW's direct DLL linking without bothering himself with DEFs at all, or use `__declspec(dllimport)` (or any substitute for it), which allows importing externs without DEF files. Yet I've noticed he uses M$ tools, so I retract my statement about DEF not being totally needed as it's a bit too strong - DEF can be omitted, I think OP used a wrong approach, but if he *insisted* on using them, your answer is 100% OK.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page indicates that `winuser.h` is the header.  From there, you can see some macros are used, including `WINUSERAPI` and `WINAPI`.  `WINUSERAPI` is conditionally `#define`-d at the beginning of that header.  `WINAPI` can be found in the `winbase.h` header, where it can be seen to be tied to a calling convention, depending on the platform.

But a better question is: Why are you using `dllexport` and not `dllimport`?

Comment: `WINAPI` is just `stdcall`: `#define WINAPI __stdcall`. `WINUSERAPI` is `DECLSPEC_IMPORT`, which is, in turn, `__declspec(dllimport)`. So, what goes before the function's name in the def is basically `__declspec(dllimport)
int
__stdcall`. I've changed dllexport to dllimport, and it's still not working (see other answer). However, I'm not sure if the `_In_opt_` and `_In_` stuff in the variables can be causing any sort of problem...

Comment: @Mints97 `_In_opt_` and `_In_` are empty macros (they're used for [SAL annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx))

Comment: +0 - although you're completely right here, Shao, this is not an answer by itself, as it doesn't address the question directly. This should be probably a comment to OP IMO.